# Streamlabs Socket Ping Timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I was trying to use socket io client to connect to Streamlabs API using Node JS. I read their doc and tried to debug. After I run the code, the server doesn't respond to my socket request. I did set up the token paste it into .env file. Here's where I got the socket token, and I believe it is correct. I got it under Streamlabs⇒Setting⇒API Settings⇒API Token⇒Your Socket API Token

[Image of where I got the token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFk7Y.png)

Here's my code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const io = require("socket.io-client");

//Connect to socket
const streamlabs = io(`https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=${process.env.SOCKET_TOKEN}`, {transports: ['websocket']});
  
console.log(`[Streamlabs]: connecting socket to https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=${process.env.SOCKET_TOKEN}\nTimestamp: ${Date.now()}\n`)

//Perform Action on event
streamlabs.on('event', (eventData) => {
    console.log(eventData)
});

streamlabs.on("connect", ()=>{
    console.log(`[Streamlabs]: socket connected \nTimestamp: ${Date.now()}\n`)
});

streamlabs.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log(`[Streamlabs]: socket disconnected \nReason: ${reason} \nTimestamp: ${Date.now()}\n`)
});
```

Expected behavior:

```
[Streamlabs]: connecting socket to https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=eyJ0...
Timestamp: 1620442...

[Streamlabs]: socket connected
Timestamp: 1620442...
```

What I got instead:

```
[Streamlabs]: connecting socket to https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=eyJ0...
Timestamp: 1620442...
    
[Streamlabs]: socket disconnected 
Reason: ping timeout 
Timestamp: 1620442...
    
[Streamlabs]: socket disconnected 
Reason: ping timeout 
Timestamp: 1620442...
```

and this goes on forever. Any idea what caused the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Self answer lol)

After A LOT of research, I ended up searching in YouTube tutorial comment section, and they suggests that the new socket io client version is not compatible with Streamlabs' API, so I have to switch to an older version of socket io client. Everything works now. Here you have it if you also have the same problem. To fix the problem, run the following command in your project directory:

```
npm install socket.io-client@2.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone like me is using python-socketio trying to figure out the same issue, the solution is the same as the accepted answer. You need to roll back python-socketio to an older version as well as one of it's dependencies. Use the 2 following commands to resolve the issue:

```sh
pip3 install 'python-socketio==5.04' --force-reinstall
pip3 install 'python-engineio==3.14.2' --force-reinstall
```